# Validation to check if related record available

Tags: related-list, error-messages

How to throw some message to user if check box is checked on parent then related record needs to be created if there is no related record in salesforce.How to achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done with a roll-up summary field of type Count as long as your related records are actually detail records in a master-detail relationship.

Otherwise, we're entering the realm of Apex Triggers.